# How can I update the first of two tables even if the second table is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

When I update two tables with this query:

```
UPDATE
    `gmw-db-051514`.`gmw_provider`,     /* Update this table... */
    `gmw-db-051514`.`tbl_conversations` /* ...even this one is empty */
SET
    `gmw_provider`.`is_partner` = true,
    `gmw_provider`.`partner_url` = 'some_url_here',
    `gmw_provider`.`partner_remove_token` = 'ABC123',
    `tbl_conversations`.`partner_initial_id` =(
CASE WHEN
    `tbl_conversations`.`user_initial_id` = '30'
THEN
    '30' ELSE `tbl_conversations`.`partner_initial_id` END),
    `tbl_conversations`.`partner_target_id` =(
CASE WHEN
    `tbl_conversations`.`user_following_id` = '30'
THEN
     '30' ELSE `tbl_conversations`.`partner_target_id` END)
WHERE`
     gmw_provider`.`provider_id` = '127'
```

This works only if there is something in the second table (tbl_conversations).

For example, the table(tbl_conversations) may look like this when its filled:

```
 |user_initial_id|user_following_id|partner_initial_id|partner_target_id|etc..|
 |     30        |        41       |       30         |        41       |etc..|
 |     51        |        41       |       NULL       |        41       |etc..|
 |     37        |        30       |       NULL       |        30       |etc..|
```

But when nothing is in the second table, I still need the first table to be updated.

How can I ignore that and say to database: It's ok when we don't update the second table when It's empty, but please ALWAYS update the first one(gmw_provider).

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.  You need an outer join.  Normally, there would be a `join` condition, but I don't see any.

I think this will work:

```
UPDATE `gmw-db-051514`.`gmw_provider` gp LEFT JOIN     /* Update this table... */
       `gmw-db-051514`.`tbl_conversations` c
       ON 1 = 1
    SET gp.`is_partner` = true,
        gp.`partner_url` = 'some_url_here',
        gp.`partner_remove_token` = 'ABC123',
        c.`partner_initial_id` = (CASE WHEN c.`user_initial_id` = 30
    T                                  THEN 30  -- assuming `id` is a number
                                       ELSE c.`partner_initial_id` 
                                 END),
        c.`partner_target_id` = (CASE WHEN c.`user_following_id` = 30
                                      THEN 30
                                      ELSE c.`partner_target_id`
                                 END)

WHERE gp.`provider_id` = 127  -- assume it is a number
```

Based on the logic, I think you do have a `JOIN` condition:

```
UPDATE `gmw-db-051514`.`gmw_provider` gp LEFT JOIN     /* Update this table... */
       `gmw-db-051514`.`tbl_conversations` c
       ON 30 IN (c.user_initial_id, c.user_following_id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon Linoff - I'll try this out and report the result. I googled the "ON 1=1" thing. I' didn't know I could do this and always thought the ON 'pairing'(?) has to be a specific reference based on existing IDs or something like that.

Comment: @user_name . . . What you want to do is unusual, but not unknown.  Essentially, you want `LEFT CROSS JOIN`, and that operator does not (explicitly) exist in SQL.